# Messages sent via yahoo using javamail api not going to sent messages folder

Tags: jakarta-mail

When i send messages from my yahoo address using javamail api, they don't go to the sent folder. What's the problem? Here's my source code:

```
public void doSendYahooMail(){
    from = txtFrom.getText();
    password= new String(txtPassword.getPassword());
    to = txtTo.getText();
    subject = txtSubject.getText();
    email_body = jTextArea1.getText();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
                }
    }
    );
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(email_body);
        Transport.send(message);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Message Sent!","Sent",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.toString());
    }
}
```

what modifications do i need to make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a copy in your sent messages folder, you need to put it there yourself.  See the [JavaMail sample program msgsend.java](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) for an example.

Also, you'll want to fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) in your program.

Comment: Thanks @BillShannon, especially for the common Javamail mistakes

Comment: Hi Bill, I've looked at the Javamail sample program msgsend.java but the last part (Read the body of the message until EOF) seems to give me problems. How do I incorporate it in the above source code

Comment: You don't need that.  The collect method is just one way to get the data that would be included in the body of the message.  You can create the message any way you want.  Once the message is created and sent, you just want to follow the block of code that shows how to save the message that was just sent.  Connect to the store, create the folder if necessary, append the message to the folder.

Comment: Hi Bill, I was looking at the common JavaMail mistakes and saw that yo do not necessarily need to use an Authenticator just to supply a username and password. Under what circumstances are you required to use an Authenticator?

Comment: You're never **required** to use an Authenticator.  Authenticators are intended for the case where you need to supply the username and password "on demand" (e.g., when prompting the user for the information using a Swing dialog box), as opposed to the cases where the username and password have been pre-configured and can just be passed to the connect or send method.