# Sending email using Apache mail is not saved in the sent folder

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, apache-commons-email

I am using Apache Commons Mail library to send email (using their simple SMTP email example).

The email is sent using one of the famous providers (i used yahoo as an example). The email was sent successfully. However when I login to my yahoo account I don't see the email in the sent folder.

Is there a flag I need to enable or some other thing I need to code to ensure that email is being saved in the sent folder?

Please assist. Thank you

Comment: You are confusing several different functions of email protocols. Saving the email in your sent folder will require an IMAP client. Sending the email only requires SMTP.

Comment: I thought IMAP is for retreiving emails. Is it a different process to save email in Sent folder? I thought when email is sent then email provider saves the email automatically ( appernetly not)

Comment: I already answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518023/messages-sent-via-yahoo-using-javamail-api-not-going-to-sent-messages-folder/37518870#37518870).

Comment: SMTP is for sending (and receiving) email. Storing email in a *folder* (even the "sent" folder), is performed with an IMAP client. SMTP doesn't have a concept of "folders", it's fire and forget.

Comment: @BillShannon This makes sense. Thanks for the reference. I wish  there is example using Apache common

Comment: This is both the bug and the feature of Apache Commons Email - it's simple because it's only trying to handle the very limited case of sending email.   Once you step out of that use case, you need to understand how to use JavaMail directly.  Once you understand how to use JavaMail directly, using it to send email is not that difficult.

Comment: Thank you. Feel free to put ur comment as an answer so I can accept it. Unless someone can put scripted code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just had the same issue an solved it by:

```
    ...
    // send the org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail
    email.send();
    copyIntoSent(email.getMailSession(), email.getMimeMessage());
}

private void copyIntoSent(final Session session, final Message msg) throws MessagingException
{
    final Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect(IMAP_HOST, SMTP_AUTH_USER, SMTP_AUTH_PWD);

    final Folder folder = (Folder) store.getFolder("Sent Items");
    if (folder.exists() == false) {
        folder.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);
    }
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    folder.appendMessages(new Message[] { msg });
}
```

Note that you must use the imap-host here, not the smtp-host. The difference about these protocols should be clear.

With kind regards

davey