# Javamail Read Body of Message Until EOF

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, yahoo

The following code is supposed to send and save messages sent via yahoomail. The sending part works OK but id does not save the sent message. I've been researching and found the following code:

```
/**
 * Read the body of the message until EOF.
 */
public static String collect(BufferedReader in) throws IOException {
String line;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append("\n");
}
return sb.toString();
}
```

How do I incorporate it in the following code?

```
public void doSendYahooMail(){
    from = txtFrom.getText();
    password= new String(txtPassword.getPassword());
    to = txtTo.getText();
    cc = txtCC.getText();
    bcc = txtBCC.getText();
    subject = txtSubject.getText();
    message_body = jtaMessage.getText();
    //String imapHost = "imap.mail.yahoo.com";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.imap.host", "imap.mail.yahoo.com");
    props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.imap.port", "993");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,null);

    try {           
        // message definition
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));
        if(!cc.equals("")){
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(cc));
        }
        if(!bcc.equals("")){
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, InternetAddress.parse(bcc));
        }
        message.setSubject(subject);
        if(!filename.equals("")){// if a file has been attached...
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(message_body);// actual message
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();// create multipart message
            // set the text message part
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);//add the text message to the multipart

            // attachment part
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String attachment = fileAbsolutePath;
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachment);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);//add the attachment to the multipart message
            // combine text and attachment
            message.setContent(multipart);
            // send the complete message
            Transport.send(message, from, password);
        }
        else{// if no file has been attached
            message.setText(message_body);
            Transport.send(message, from, password);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Message Sent!","Sent",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        filename = "";//reset filename to null after message is sent
        fileAbsolutePath = "";//reset absolute path name to null after message is sent

        // save sent message
        Store store = session.getStore("imap");
        store.connect(from, password);
        Folder folder = store.getFolder("Sent");
        if(!folder.exists()){
            folder.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);
            Message[] msg = new Message[1];
            msg[0] = message;
            folder.appendMessages(msg);
        }
        store.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Messages sent via yahoo using javamail api not going to sent messages folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518023/messages-sent-via-yahoo-using-javamail-api-not-going-to-sent-messages-folder)

Comment: Yeah, almost similar, but source code is modified a little bit. Note that it includes a part to save the sent message to the "Sent" folder. But still it doesn't save. Anything wrong with the source code?

Comment: Uh, ya.  You only append the message if the folder doesn't exist.

Comment: I've just realized that. Let me try it out and I'll let you know if it works

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot